# docker-compose config invalid output when replacing env variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to generate multiple instances of the same git repository with a generic docker-compose.yml file and multiple .env files.

For this somewhere in the code I generate a temporary folder which contains:

.env:

```
APP_PORT="3000"
APP_NAME="app-name"
REPO_NAME="repo-name"
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
  web-app:
    image: golang:alpine
    environment:
      - APP_PORT
      - APP_NAME
      - REDIS_HOST=db-app
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}
    volumes:
      - /opt/docker/repositories/${REPO_NAME}:/app
    command: sh -c "cd /app && go run ./"
  db-app:
    image: redis:alpine
```

then running `docker-compose config` in this directory gives me the following output :

```yaml
services:
  db-app:
    image: redis:alpine
  web-app:
    command: sh -c "cd /app && go run ./"
    environment:
      APP_NAME: app-name
      APP_PORT: '3000'
      REDIS_HOST: db-app
    image: golang:alpine
    ports:
    - published: 3000
      target: 3000
    volumes:
    - /opt/docker/repositories/repo-name:/app:rw
version: '3.6'
```

This did not only interpolate env variables, it also changed some fields such as ports with published and target, and a :rw at the end of my volume.

This is all done in Go, and when I try to unmarshal the output into a Go struct with yaml fields, it is not recognized as a valid docker-compose file because of the `ports` field (which is supposed to be an array of strings).

How can I make it so docker-compose config only replaces the ${APP_PORT} with its value and not add these extra unwanted fields ?

Comment: This doesn't really seem like you're using Docker for anything besides a way to get the `go` compiler.  Would it be more straightforward to install the compiler and `go build` each package, rather than trying to wrap it in a Compose setup?

Comment: hm no, this is a minimalistic example here but this is aimed to be deployed to a swarm along with several more complex stacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the source code, I found [this](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/c81046aac0ce1360f1bab64368f9a318c593d82a/compose/config/types.py#L426-L427) in the config types:

```py
def legacy_repr(self):
    return normalize_port_dict(self.repr())
```

Which is the representation you need. So I searched for `legacy_repr` in the source code and found [this](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/c81046aac0ce1360f1bab64368f9a318c593d82a/compose/config/serialize.py#L139-L143):

```py
if 'ports' in service_dict:
    service_dict['ports'] = [
        p.legacy_repr() if p.external_ip or version < VERSION else p
        for p in service_dict['ports']
    ]
```

So apparently, to trigger the use of the legacy representation, you either need to have an external IP address or need to do something with the version. I tried to downgrade the `docker-compose.yaml` file version but it didn't change anything (maybe it's the docker-compose CLI's version instead).

Reading the spec of the docker-compose config file, in the [ports](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#ports) section, you can specify the IP address in the short syntax:

`[HOST:]CONTAINER[/PROTOCOL]` where:

- `HOST` is `[IP:](port | range)`
- `CONTAINER` is `port | range`
- `PROTOCOL` to restrict port to specified protocol. `tcp` and `udp` values are defined by the specification, Compose implementations MAY offer support for platform-specific protocol names.

So a solution is to replace `${APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}` by:

```
0.0.0.0:${APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}
```

By setting the external IP address to `0.0.0.0` you are not restricting anything **and** you force the use of the legacy representation.

Comment: it does work with this, thank you very much ! never seen the localhost specified here before